# Eclipse Device Chooser not considering the "upgraded" android version of my Android mobile phone

Tags: android, eclipse

I upgraded my Samsung Android phone using a custom ROM (Nemesis One) from GingerBread (SDK v 10) to JellyBean 4.2.1.

I have set the minimum SDK version for my Android application as 11 and target SDK as 18.

But my eclipse device chooser does not show my phone as a listed device. However, when I reduce the minimum sdk version in my Android Manifest to 10, it shows up.

Does this mean that the Android version of my phone is still the previous one (GingerBread)?

My Samsung Phone's "About Phone" page details are as follows:

Model - GT- s5360
Android Version - 4.2.1
BaseBand Version - S5360DDKK1
Kernel Version - 2.6.35.7 root @DELL130#1
Build Number - Nemesis One

Is it because of the kernel version(2.6.35)?

Comment: Try adb kill-server and then start-server

Comment: @IronBlossom after doing adb kill-server and then start-server when the device was connected by USB to my laptop, nothing changed. The device is still not listed in the list of devices of the device chooser.  BTW, I forgot to mention in my original post that when I run the command adb devices from the command line, it shows my device. But the eclipse device chooser only shows it when I change my min sdk version from 11 to 10.

Comment: Create a sample project with android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT and see what value it returns. May be a TextView or even Log. I guess your rom is api 10.
P.S. try wipe dalvik cache from CWM

Comment: @IronBlossom ok I'll try and let you know